# SSRS How to Get Report Cache Options With Powershell?

Tags: web-services, powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

In SSRS web interface, after clicking on a report and going to Manage --> Caching if a report is configured to "Always run this report against pregenerated snapshots" there is a **Cache snapshots** section with an option "Create cache snapshots on a schedule"

[image]

I have been messing around with PowerShell and trying to create a scriptthe finds all of the reports where this option is set, and output the schedule.

I have this script that iterates over each report with "Execution Type" of "Snapshot", but I believe I'm calling the wrong method (GetCacheOptions), as all it returns is False for each item:

```
Clear-Host 

$webServiceUrl = 'http://myReportServer.domain.com/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx?WSDL'

$rs = New-WebServiceProxy -Class 'RS' -Namespace 'RS' -Uri $webServiceUrl -UseDefaultCredential

$reports = $rs.ListChildren("/Some Folder", $true) | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "Report" }

$schedDef = New-Object RS.ScheduleDefinition
$expDef = New-Object RS.ExpirationDefinition

foreach ($report in $reports) {

    $execType = $rs.GetExecutionOptions($report.Path, [ref]$schedDef.Item)


    if($execType -eq "Snapshot") {
        $rs.GetCacheOptions($report.Path, [ref]$expDef.Item)
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what method needs to be called to get this information and how to call this method (i.e. what parameters needs to be supplied)?

**EDIT:**

Per guidance from accepted answer, I was able to make some edits (below) and I'm not getting the schedule information I desire:

```
.......
....
foreach ($report in $reports) {

    $execResult = $rs.GetExecutionOptions($report.Path,
        [ref]$ScheduleDefinitionOrReference)

    if ($execResult -eq "Snapshot") {
        if($ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.Item -is [RS.DailyRecurrence]) {
            Write-Host "$($report.Name):" -f Green
            Write-Host "`tSchedule Information:" -f Yellow
            Write-Host "`t`tEvery $($ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.Item.Daysinterval) Day(s)"
            Write-Host "`t`tStart Time: $($ScheduleDefinitionOrReference.StartDateTime)`n"
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ReportingService2010.GetItemHistoryOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getitemhistoryoptions.aspx) and pass the `ItemPath`, and `out bool KeepExecutionSnapshots`, and `out ScheduleDefinitionOrReference` to the method.

`ScheduleDefinitionOrReference` will contain the `ScheduleDefinition` if you check *Create cache snapshots on a schedule*, otherwise its value will be `NoSchedule`.

**Example**

```
$svcUrl = 'http://the-host-name/ReportServer/reportservice2010.asmx'
$svc = New-WebServiceProxy -Class 'RS' -Namespace 'RS' -Uri $svcUrl -UseDefaultCredential
$reports = $svc.ListChildren("/", $true) | Where-Object { $_.TypeName -eq "Report" }

$KeepExecutionSnapshots = $false
$ScheduleDefinitionOrReference = New-Object RS.ScheduleDefinitionOrReference

foreach ($report in $reports) {
    $svc.GetItemHistoryOptions($report.Path, 
        [ref]$KeepExecutionSnapshots, 
        [ref]$ScheduleDefinitionOrReference)
    $report.Path
    $ScheduleDefinitionOrReference
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but you got me going in the right direction! Thanks! I was able to use the GetExecutionOptions() method, but I was misunderstanding how to properly use the [ref] variable. Included some updates to my answer just for anyone to see what/how I was able to get what I needed working. Thanks again!

Comment: FYI, won't let me award bounty for 18 hours. I will be sure to do so once I am able!

Comment: You're welcome. I tested `GetItemHistoryOptions`, as I described if you check *Create cache snapshots on a schedule* the ScheduleDefinitionOrReference  parameter will contain the schedule object, otherwise its value will be NoSchedule. So I guess you can use it as well. I didn't checked GetExecutionOptions but based on the documentations, it does the trick for you. If the execution options for an item do not contain schedule information, the output parameter is the schedule otherwise the Item parameter is a NoScheduleobject.